# Can I set an event handler in initializer?

Tags: c#, eventhandler

I write next code:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
timer.Tick += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    //...
};
timer.Start();
```

But I wanna write this more simply with the intializer.

So, I tried this:

```
new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    Tick += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        //...
    }
}.Start();
```

But it occurs errors(CS0103, CS0747).

Is it impossible expression?

Answer (score 1):

The stuff in the curly brackets is the initializer section in which you can initialize public properties or fields only.  The line

```
Tick += etc
```

Is not initializing Tick, it is adding an event handler to it using += which is not possible.

You can however use this constructor:

```
new DispatcherTimer(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    (sender, args) =>
    {
    //...
    },
    Application.Current.Dispatcher)
        .Start();
```

Personally I think the several lines of code option is easier to read.